# Meaning of "ein Muss" in a german

Tags: german-to-english, grammar-identification

> Eine Krankenversicherung ist fuer jeden Einwohner ein Muss

Could someone explain what the 'ein Muss' means in the above?

Comment: What is left open after looking at the dictionary page in [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Muss)? I'm inclined to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: @guidot: It's also in [English Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Muss#German). I wouldn't expect beginners to be able to read DWDS, but if the word is in an English dictionary then I agree that the question is closable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"ein Muss" means "a must". "Muss" is a noun, related to the verb "müssen".